# How do I change language for a page?

Tags: 8

How do I change language from `<html lang="en">` to `<html lang="en-GB">`?

Comment: add `html.tpl.php` file in your theme and add your language as `lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>`

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1689874

Comment: i am talking about  drupal 8 not drupal 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change langcode](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307517/change-langcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change default language to English on this page `/admin/config/regional/language`

[image]