# Change langcode

Tags: 8

How can I change the entire site `<html lang="en">` to `<html lang="en-US">`? I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: Question is too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically you can use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.0.x) like the this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function [MODULE|THEME]_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute $html_attribute */
  $html_attribute = $variables['html_attributes'];
  if ($html_attribute->hasAttribute("lang")) {
    $html_attribute->removeAttribute('lang');
    $html_attribute->setAttribute('lang', 'en-US');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding `en-US` as a custom language.

1. Go to `/admin/config/regional/language`.
2. Click **Add language**.
3. Choose **Custom language...** from the bottom of the list.
4. Enter the language code and language name.

Comment: But what if there's existing content? Like 1000 nodes, all in `en`?

Comment: @leymannx If the site is monolingual, you can just delete the original `en` English.  If there are multiple languages, you can probably use VBO to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 and laters can handle this via UI.

This is how I set proper `lang` code in a multilanguage content website.

- add/set up languages [/admin/config/regional/language]
- set up language detection (optional) [/admin/config/regional/language/detection]
- set up language behaviours for a multilanguge content type  you want translated in more languages [/admin/config/regional/content-language]
- translate your node in more languages.

You can now switch node traslation and compare `lang` codes